# How to create a simple Boids model with Canvas and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, boids

I need to create a simple behavior model, but nowhere find a detailed manual. Some resources give me a code on other programming languages, but practically is no one write full details of this. Help, please.

Comment: You came to the wrong place if you expect us to produce code without any base code, or any efforts shown in the first place. What is your code so far? How would you proceed to try implementing this?

Comment: I need rather only detailed manual rather than code of this.